# Rails3 - oauth-plugin problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth

I'm trying to use [`oauth-plugin`](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) on a `Rails` application I'm developing, but I keep running into problems.

To make sure I'm not making any mistake, I started an application from scratch (using Rails 3.0.3). Here are the steps I followed:

1. Create da new rails application (`rails.test`)
2. Edited its `Gemfile` to include:

   ```
   gem "oauth-plugin", ">=0.4.0.pre1"
   gem "oauth", "0.4.4"
   ```
3. Generated `oauth-consumer`, by running `script/rails g oauth_consumer`
4. Edited `oauth_consumers.rb` to include my keys for Google integration:

   ```
   :google=>{ 
     :key=>"anonymous", 
     :secret=>"anonymous",
     :scope=>"https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/", 
     :options => {
       :site => "http://www.google.com", 
       :request_token_path => "/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken", 
       :access_token_path => "/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken", 
       :authorize_path=> "/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken"
     },
   }
   ```
5. Edited `routes.rb` to add the route for `oauth_consumer`:

   ```
   resources :oauth_consumers
   ```
6. Edited `application_controller.rb` to implement the `logged_in?` method as follows:

   ```
   def logged_in?
       true
   end
   ```
7. Now when I access `http://localhost:3000/oauth_consumers/google` I get the following error:

   ```
   uninitialized constant GoogleToken
   ```

Does anyone know what causes this error and how can I fix it? `GoogleToken` is a class that should have been auto generated by `oauth-plugin`, so I can't tell why I'm getting this uninitialized constant error.

Answer (score 3):

The GoogleToken class doesn't get auto-generated unless you pass "google" to the generator like so:

```
script/rails g oauth_consumer google
```

or for rails 3:

```
rails g oauth_consumer google
```

Also check to ensure the relationship is set up in the user model like so:

```
has_one  :google, :class_name => "GoogleToken", :dependent => :destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to run `bundle install` from terminal after editing your `Gemfile`? Sounds like your Rails app doesn't know about these gems yet.

Comment: I did. All the gems are installed.

Comment: Sounds like that file is supposed to be generated at some point by the plugin, but I can't seem to figure out when/where.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i think a solution could be in this:
https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/blob/master/lib/generators/oauth_consumer/USAGE
You need some sort of authentication like restful-authentication plugin, if you uncomment line 27..29 in your oauth_consumers_controller.rb file, you'll jump to next step!