# 401 Unauthorized error in Rails two-legged OAuth provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, oauth-ruby, two-legged

I'm trying to implement a two-legged OAuth provider on Rails.

I followed these instruction for installing the consumer and provider:

https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin

with these instructions to make the consumer work

[Rails3 - oauth-plugin problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925746/rails3-oauth-plugin-problem)

These instruction to implement the user login

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

And used these methods to test the connection

http://oauth.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/OAuth/Consumer.html

Followed these instructions for implementing the two-legged strategy

[Rails two-legged OAuth provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775242/rails-two-legged-oauth-provider)

But on the consumer side I get

```
  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 86ms
  OAuth::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized ):
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
  ...
```

and on server side

```
Started POST "/oauth/request_token" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jan 06 22:02:08 -0300 2013
Processing by OauthController#request_token as */*
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as #   <OAuth::Controllers::ApplicationControllerMethods::Filter:0x1111e0e80 @strategies=[:two_legged], @options={:interactive=>false, :strategies=>:two_legged}> rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (Views: 2.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

This post seems to point to the same issue

https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/issues/106

I'm using two-legged implementation to allow login to my rails app from my native android app.

This post seems to be related with my problem

[Rails Oauth: unable to get request_token, filter chain halted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207341/rails-oauth-unable-to-get-request-token-filter-chain-halted)

I don't know where to look or how to get a more detailed log on the server side.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!